# SQL взять строку и сразу обновить

Tags: sql

Есть таблица с промокодами, в них есть 2 поля - `Code`, `IsUsed`

Когда я беру код из таблицы, это выглядит как

```
SELECT Code FROM Codes WHERE IsUsed == '0' LIMIT 1;
```

Только теперь мне нужно этот код пометить с `IsUsed = 1`.

Вопрос: как взять значение из таблицы, и одновременно с этим изменить поле в нём?

Comment: в общем случае никак, но зависит от СУБД. В MS SQL можете сделать `update ... output updated.*`. А еще лучше обратить внимание на то, что если у вас несколько записей попадае под критерий `isUsed = 0`, то выбираете/обновляет вы какую-то произвольную из них. В целом скорее всего там будет запись в порядке кластеризации или первичного ключа, но в общем это никак не гарантировано.

Comment: На самом деле во многих диалектах есть такие возможности, но они очень сильно отличаются в разных СУБД. Так что необходимо знать какая же база данных (и какой версии) используется

Comment: Укажите ТОЧНО используемую СУБД, включая версию. Без этой информации, в общем, можно посоветовать только использовать блокирующую транзакцию, которая сперва выбирает одну запись, а потом её обновляет. PS. По-моему, ни в одной СУБД нет оператора `==`.. хотя могу и ошибаться.